# Who are these people in the pictures in Adam's room?

Tags: reference, props, only-lovers-left-alive

In *Only Lovers Left Alive*, Adam has a wall of pictures of famous people.

They appear to be authors, composers, and scientists.

Who are they?

Comment: @Catija Jarmusch wrote and directed the film, and as seen from the page linked in the answer, many of the subjects of the photos are connected to Jarmusch in some other way as well. Since he selected the people to show on the "wall of heroes", isn't this question implicitly about him?

Comment: That is not how tagging works here. How could the question "implicitly be about him" if you **never** mention him in the question? Regardless, your question is about the film, not about the director. We tag things based on the question, what the answer reveals is irrelevant.

Comment: @Catija Fair enough. To be honest I am somewhat confused as to how tagging is supposed to work on this SE. On SO, the idea seems to be that if a tag is relevant to a question, it's good to use the tag so that followers of that tag would see the question. If that were the case here, it seems you'd want people interested in Jarmusch to see this question. But the tags that exist seem so disparate (one for every movie??) that I don't really understand the value of tags here.

Answer (score 9):

A complete list of the people in the photos, together with screenshots of the wall, [has been compiled here](http://draculahistoryandmyth.com/only-lovers-left-alive-adams-wall-heroes/). The site also mentions some behind-the-scenes connections between the subjects of the photos and the other films of Jim Jarmusch (the film's director).

[image]

Their names (numbered according to the labels in the above photo) are:

1. Joe Strummer
2. Johann Sebastian Bach
3. Claire Denis
4. Mary Wollstonecraft
5. Aki Kaurismäki
6. Bo Diddley
7. Franz Schubert
8. Chrissie Hynde
9. Franz Kafka
10. Edgar Allen Poe
11. Bruce Lee
12. RZA
13. Screamin’ Jay Hawkins
14. Gustav Mahler
15. Henry Purcell
16. Tom Waits
17. Charles Baudelaire
18. Luis Buñuel
19. William S. Burroughs
20. Sitting Bull
21. Max Ernst and Dorothea Tanning
22. Robert Johnson
23. Buster Keaton
24. Nikola Tesla
25. Rumi
26. William Blake
27. Arthur Rimbaud
28. Hedy Lamarr
29. Patti Smith
30. Charley Patton
31. Emily Dickinson
32. Jean-Michel Basquiat
33. Robby Müller
34. John Coltrane
35. Mark Twain
36. Isaac Newton
37. Marcel Duchamp
38. Fritz Lang
39. Naomi Klein
40. Frank Zappa
41. Iggy Pop
42. Thelonious Monk
43. Harpo Marx
44. Susan Sontag
45. Black Elk
46. Rodney Dangerfield
47. Christopher Marlowe
48. Geronimo
49. Samuel Beckett
50. Jane Austen
51. John Keats
52. Oscar Wilde
53. Jimi Hendrix
54. Nicholas Ray
55. Hank Williams
56. Billie Holiday
57. Neil Young